# SP1 says "the expected version of the product was not found on the system."

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, upgrade, installation

Just installed SharePoint on a brand new vm server so I can add it to the dev farm. Restarted the machine. I am trying to run sp1 from kb2460045 and getting the above error message. I have no tracking as to which service pack and CU are in the farm so I can install them in that order.

This command does not help to resolve the issue

```
Get-SPProduct -Local | Select -Property ProductName
```

Here is the upgrade and patch screen from central admin from the farm.

> Microsoft Access Services English Language Pack    14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6105.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Access Services Server    14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6120.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Document Lifecycle Components 14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5004  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6134.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6120.5004  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Document Lifecycle Components English Language Pack   14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6128.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6120.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Excel Mobile Viewer Components    14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5004  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6134.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6118.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Excel Services Components 14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5004  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6134.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6118.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Excel Services English Language Pack  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6105.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft InfoPath Form Services English Language Pack  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6123.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6108.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft InfoPath Forms Services   14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5003  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6128.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6120.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Office Server Proof (Arabic) 2010 14.0.6028.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6105.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6028.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Office Server Proof (English) 2010    14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6129.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6120.5004  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Office Server Proof (French) 2010 14.0.6028.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6105.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6028.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Office Server Proof (German) 2010 14.0.6028.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6105.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6028.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Office Server Proof (Russian) 2010    14.0.6028.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6105.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6028.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Office Server Proof (Spanish) 2010    14.0.6028.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6119.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6028.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Search Server 2010 Core   14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5004  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6134.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6120.5004  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Search Server 2010 English Language Pack  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6128.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6120.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Shared Components 14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5004  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6134.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6120.5004  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Shared Coms English Language Pack 14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6128.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6120.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 1033 Lang Pack 14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 (KB2817552) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6131.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6120.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 Core   14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 (KB2817552) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5004  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6134.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6120.5006  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft SharePoint Portal 14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5004  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6134.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6120.5004  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft SharePoint Portal English Language Pack   14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6133.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6105.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010    14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Slide Library 14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6120.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Slide Library English Language Pack   14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft User Profiles 14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5004  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6134.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6120.5004  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Visio Services English Language Pack  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Visio Services Web Front End Components   14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6124.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6120.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Web Analytics English Language Pack   14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6105.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Web Analytics Web Front End Components    14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6130.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6107.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Word Server   14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5004  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6134.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6119.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Microsoft Word Server English Language Pack 14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6128.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6115.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   PerformancePoint Services for SharePoint    14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6134.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6120.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   PerformancePoint Services in SharePoint 1033 Language Pack  14.0.6029.1000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2817527) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.7102.5000  Installed
>   Hotfix for Microsoft SharePoint Server 2010 (KB2767793) 64-Bit Edition  14.0.6131.5000  Superseded
>   Hotfix for Microsoft Office Server (KB2598151)  14.0.6117.5000  Superseded
>   Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Service Pack 1 (SP1)  14.0.6029.1000  Installed

Comment: why you trying to install the Services pack as Central admin showing it is already installed, can you check the buuild version of the sahrepoint? from central admin > manager server in farm.

Comment: I am trying to add another sp server to sharepoint dev farm. so I am making sure it has the same sp and cu. Configuration database version: 14.0.7102.5004

Comment: so the new server is not part of the farm. Did you reboot the server after installing the SharePoint? also can you see the SharePoint in Add/remove program?

Comment: The new server is not part of the farm yet. Yes, I have rebooted the server after the initial SP install. control panel shows SharePoint 2010 with 14.0.6029.1000

Comment: i would try to repair the sharepoint first. re run the setup of SharePoint and select repair it.once completed then try to install the SP1

Comment: Okay. started the repair process. I will keep the post updated.

Comment: Repair completed with a restart prompt. Restarted the machine. Ran the SP1 KB2460045 and got the same error. Tried to run the SP Foundation sp1 kb2460058 and it gives me "the update is already installed on this system."

Comment: try to donwload the fresh copy from Microsoft site again and what is the size of file?

Comment: 396334kb is the size of the server sp1

Comment: one thing, you are on the 6029 on new server which is SharePoint 2010 with SP1.You need to install the SP2 for sharepoint then June cu 2013.

Comment: do I need to install foundations too? or just server piece

Comment: just server piece, as Foundation is part of the Server now

Comment: install office sp 2. report the expected version of the product was not found on the system. office version 14.0.4734.1000 (32 bit)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with Office 2010 Profession Plus. The issue appeared after upgrading my windows from 8.1 to 10.

The only solution was to use Microsoft's easy fix "brute uninstaller" and reinstalled office (I used Windows 8 version on my Windows 10 and it worked like a charm).

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/971179

God bless!